# Как правильно сделать конструктор копирования в классе?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test{
    public:
        Test(){
            name="First";
            mas=1;
            get();
        };
        Test(string a, double b){
            name=a;
            mas=b;
            get();
        };
        Test(const Test &test):
            name(test.name), mas(test.mas){
                cout<<"Copy constructor worked here!\n";
                get();
            };
    private:
        string name;
        double mas; 
    void get(){
        cout << "Name = " << name << "\n" << "Mas = " << mas << endl;
    };
};
int main() {
    Test *first = new Test();
    Test *second = new Test("dadad", 12);
    Test copyfirst(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Сделал класс и 3 конструктора(по умолчанию, с параметрами и конструктор копирования) Не понимаю как правильно сделать конструктор копирования с динамическими типами данными, сверху код с моей попыткой.

Comment: `Test copyfirst(first);` -> `Test copyfirst(*first);`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() {
    Test *first = new Test();
    Test *second = new Test("dadad", 12);
    Test copyfirst(*first);
```

`Test copyfirst(first); -> Test copyfirst(*first);`

Comment: Скажите, а зачем приводить весь код ради одной измененной строчки?...